# Calling different Assets the same way - error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, assets

I added two sound files to my assets folder. One is a sound for "right" and the other one is a sound for "wrong".

I wrote two functions, each one to play one of that sounds `playRight()` and `playWrong()`.

Here is the code:

```
 public void playWrong(){
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("Wrong");
            MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
            m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();

            m.prepare();
            m.start();
        }catch (IOException e){
        }
    }

    public void playRight(){
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("Right");
            MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
            m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            descriptor.close();

            m.prepare();
            m.start();
        }catch (IOException e){
        }
    }
```

Starting the function `playWrong()` works fine and I can hear the sound. But starting `playRight()` gets me an exception although it seems to me that both functions should work the same way.

Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: show exception which is through when click on Right Button

Comment: add this in your catch cluase and then send your logcat : `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: and also check your sounds file names it might be the reason of your problem

Comment: @Milad : It might not be an `IOException` - the OP should create a catch-all `Exception` catch block.

Comment: 03-16 10:02:40.715  27914-27914/com.example.cello.myownquiz W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

Comment: But both files were a .mp3 and I cut .mp3 away for both files. Why is it working with one?

Comment: is the playRight file bigger than playWrong?

Comment: I loaded the mp3 files in audacity and exported them as mp3 again. Now it works with both... weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
public void playRight() {
try {
    if (m.isPlaying()) {
        m.stop();
        m.release();
        m = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("Right.mp3");
    m.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
    descriptor.close();

    m.prepare();       
    m.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: That is excactly my code. Only a state test at the beginning.